# Parsing string for object property

Tags: c#, string, parsing, replace, reflection

How do I convert "Account" in to

```
<Account>
```

or "Object Name" into

```
<Object with matching name>
```

I'm attempting to parse a string and replace values in a string with object properties.

This is similar to what we do with form letters we send out, you know the Dear [Customer Name], thank you for purchasing [Some Item].  In this case the fields in the letter aren't setup by me and I need a means of converting what is in the text block into an object property.

Currently I'm using a code in the string {value=x; id=y ;property=z} and running that through a switch case to convert it into an object.  Then replacing the {} with the object properties.

for example "some random string {value=1; id=1; property=Name} continued random string"

I parse the string to locate {value=, on a hit it runs through a switch case, where on case 1: return Account(ID = 1).   The I grab Account.Name

Once I have that I put it in a text box so the user can validate that it is correct before generating a final document to be sent out.

Is there a way to have {Object.Property} in the string then use reflection to convert that string value to the object value?

[Get property value from string using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection)

I used the above in other instances, but that requires that I have the object.

Comment: I've removed your ASP.NET tag as there isn't anything related to ASP.NET in your question content. I'm wondering why you're trying to reinvent the wheel and make a poor man's JSON?

Comment: Can you use JSON to do this?  blah blah blah {Account.Name} blah blah blah. I've used it to grab an object but not replacing sections from a string.  It could also be {Person.Name} or {Car.Name}.  I'm not familiar with a way to do this with JSON

Comment: Can you please decide for one pattern that you use? You posted: [token], {token} , {C#_object} and "token". Looks like you should use regular expressions to match your pattern and to return the index(es) of any match(es).

Comment: Thank you Oliver for continuing to make SO the place it is....

Comment: @OlivierRogier would be cool if knowing the answer was a prerequisite for downvoting it.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static List<string> GetClassProperties(string className, IEnumerable<string> propertiesToExclude = null)
        {
            Type theType = Type.GetType(className);
            if (theType == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
}
```

This'll get you the Object type, you do need the full namespace for it to work, can't just be "Account" would need to be Project.Models.Account

Comment: This is not about reflection but parsing strings!

Comment: Also the null check is totally redundant if you return null anyway.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain you don't understand what I'm asking.   I was asking how to convert "Account" into the object account.  That's why the question was tagged with reflection originally

Comment: It's reasonably certain that you don't understand what reflection is. How does reflection help you to create instances of an object and initialize it with a value you extract from a string?

Comment: There is a strong mapping between string values and onjects. The easiest is to use JSON as it is easily editable even using a text editor and you can directly create instances of the related C# object from it using serialization. You don't need reflection for this job, believe me.

Comment: If your string contains strong type information consider to use XML, which also supports deserialization into plain C# objects.

Comment: @BionicCode The users are able to create template forms, they can add in data from objects in the database.  The users create a string that has their text then {value= x} which I parse when I want to send the form.  I convert their input into the values of the object in the database.  For example the users could create a form that has Hello [Person Name].  I parse the text to find [Person Name] then I convert "Person Name" into the database object Person.Name.  How do you downvote when I figured out how to do what I wanted to do... This is why people hate asking questions on SO.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. I did downvote your question as it lacks some crucial details in order to provide a useful answer.